# How to change name of jar created using shadowjar

Tags: gradle, jar, build

I am using shadowJar plugin to build/create my fatJar . Inside my build.gradle I have this

```
shadowJar{
mergeServiceFiles('META-INF/spring.*')
exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
exclude "META-INF/LICENSE"
}
```

Using gradle shadowJar creates my fat jar . However the name of the fat jar created is something sample-SNAPSHOT-ns.r100-all.jar  . I want to change it to sample-SNAPSHOT-ns.r100-deploy.jar . How do u overwrite jar Name using ShadowJar.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The ShadowJar plugin provides a Jar task extension. Configure it using the [archiveFileName](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveFileName) property, such as:

```
shadowJar{
    mergeServiceFiles('META-INF/spring.*')
    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    exclude "META-INF/LICENSE"
    archiveFileName = "sample-${classifier}-ns.r100-deploy.${extension}"
}
```

You can use placeholders like `${baseName}`, `${appendix}`, `${version}`, `${classifier}` and `${extension}`.

Note that `archiveName` is now `archiveFileName`, as of ShadowJar version 4.

Comment: The Shadow plugin default is `archiveName = "${baseName}-${version}-${classifier}.${extension}"`

Comment: @mernst that command in my build.gradle file throws error `Could not get unknown property 'baseName' for root project`

Answer (score 10):

For people looking how to do this with the Kotlin DSL it this:

```
tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
   archiveFileName.set("${archiveBaseName}-${archiveVersion}-${archiveClassifier}.${archiveExtension}")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

combining the answers of @richard and @christian-dräger

```
tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
    archiveFileName.set("${project.name}-${project.version}.jar")
}
```

this outputs the format `myProject-0.0.1.jar`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to replace `-all` by `-deploy` only, just add classifier option to shadowjar:

```
shadowJar{
  mergeServiceFiles('META-INF/spring.*')
  exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
  exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
  exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
  exclude "META-INF/LICENSE"
  archiveName = "sample-${classifier}-ns.r100-deploy.${extension}"
  classifier = 'deploy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Richards answer i like to do the following to configure the task by usage of the kotlin DSL:

```
tasks {
    val shadowJar by getting(ShadowJar::class) {
        archiveFileName.set("${project.name}-${project.version}-foo.jar")
    }
}
```